# Find previous number in string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table "GEM" in a database with a unique column **SPName**.
The value of each record consists of  one char and number example

> F12, T16, K15, F10 , K14, T9, T7

I would like to find the number just before the selected one
for example :

> Input: F12  Output:F10
>
> Input: T9 output:T7
>
> Input: T16 output: T9

I was thinking of removing any none numeric then do db search for each number before the input one, but sound like it will be bad performance.

```
    Gem gem;
    for(i= input; i>0; i--)
    {
        gem = Uow.Gems.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x=> RemoveChar(x.SpName) == input) 
        If(gem!=null) break;
    }
```

Any tip?

Comment: The best thing, if possible, would be to change your DB to separate the letter and number into separate columns.

Comment: Thx juharr, but i'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: have you tested it before calling it bad performance? If not, I suggest you do.

Comment: If it really yield a bad performance, you could try adding `Calculated Column` to help you do your query. If you're using SQL Server, then you can also look at the [OVER clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: Just tested it, as i expected average 36 seconds for one record. 
I cannot modify any tbl in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly way (without exception handling etc...) to do what you want :

Important note : don't forget that the best way to do that is to change your db by adding a column as *juharr* told you.

```
    List<string> ints = new List<string>();
    ints.Add("F12");
    ints.Add("T16");
    ints.Add("K15");
    ints.Add("F10");
    ints.Add("K14");
    ints.Add("T9");
    ints.Add("T7");

    var ordered = ints.Select((s, i) => new
    {
        nb = int.Parse(s.Substring(1)),
        text = s.Substring(0, 1),
        val = s,
    }).OrderBy(arg => arg.text).ThenBy(arg => arg.nb).ToList();

    var index = ordered.FindIndex(arg => arg.val == "T16");
    Console.WriteLine(ordered[index - 1].val);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why add `FindIndex` as extension class? LINQ offers that method.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will return the value you are after;

```
    public string GetPrevious(string value)
    {
        var list = new[]
        {
            new {SPName = "F12"},
            new {SPName = "T16"},
            new {SPName = "K15"},
            new {SPName = "F10"},
            new {SPName = "K14"},
            new {SPName = "T9"},
            new {SPName = "T7"}
        };

        return
            list.Where(
                l => l.SPName.ToCharArray().First() == value.ToCharArray().First() &&
                    GetValue(l.SPName) < GetValue(value)).OrderByDescending(l => GetValue(l.SPName)).First().SPName;
    }

    public int GetValue(string value)
    {
        return int.Parse(value.Substring(1, value.Length - 1));
    }
```

Unfortunately its hard to know how fast this will run with many values without having your original table data (I'm not suggesting you post it).

Comment: the table has 1,431,600 records

Comment: I guessed it would be something like that, have you tried filtering by string length (since your result would never be longer than your input?). You basically need some efficient way of reducing the size of your set before doing the slow stuff.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, not sure of performance, but should give you a `SPName LIKE 'T%@'` in the SQL so should use the index:

```
var input = "T9";
var Gem = Uow.Gems.Where
       (g => g.SPName.StartsWith(input.Substring(0,1)) &&
              Convert.ToInt32(g.SPName.Substring(1)) <
                  Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(1)))
    .OrderByDescending(g => Convert.ToInt32(g.SPName.Substring(1)))
    .Take(1);
```

I reckon this should generate this SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'F%'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1
DECLARE @p2 Int = 12
DECLARE @p3 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[SPName]
FROM [Gem] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[SPName] LIKE @p0) AND ((CONVERT(Int,SUBSTRING([t0].[SPName], @p1 + 1, CONVERT(Int,DATALENGTH([t0].[SPName]))))) < @p2)
ORDER BY CONVERT(Int,SUBSTRING([t0].[SPName], @p3 + 1, CONVERT(Int,DATALENGTH([t0].[SPName])))) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have an approach using a simple cache which populates all gems and the order them using comparer.

```
        //  Use your Uow.Gems.GetAll() list of gems 
        string[] gems = new string[] { "F12", "T16", "K15", "F10", "K14", "T9", "T7", "A12", "A11" };

        string input = "A12";

        //Cache it something like this Uow.Gems.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x, new GemComparer()).ToList()
        var cacheGems = gems.OrderBy(x => x, new GemComparer());

        foreach (var thing in cacheGems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(thing);
        }

        var previous = cacheGems.TakeWhile(x => x != input).LastOrDefault();

        var next = cacheGems.SkipWhile(x => x != input).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(previous);

        Console.WriteLine(next);
```

Will be empty if not found

`A11
A12
F10
F12
K14
K15
T16
T7
T9'`

Output: previous :  A11 , Next F10

```
    public class GemComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
        {
            if (IsNumeric(s1) && IsNumeric(s2))
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(s1) > Convert.ToInt32(s2)) return 1;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(s1) < Convert.ToInt32(s2)) return -1;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(s1) == Convert.ToInt32(s2)) return 0;
            }

            if (IsNumeric(s1) && !IsNumeric(s2))
                return -1;

            if (!IsNumeric(s1) && IsNumeric(s2))
                return 1;

            return string.Compare(s1, s2, true);
        }

        public static bool IsNumeric(object value)
        {
            try
            {
                int i;
                return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```